# Android Resource not found when TextView setText

Tags: android, textview

This crash happens randomly. In most case, it works fine, the String resource could be found properly. I googled this and seems my case is different with others

The code is like below

```
     if (mType == Constants.TYPE_POWER) {
        mStatus.setText(R.string.power_on);
    } else if (mType == Constants.TYPE_USB) {
        mStatus.setText(R.string.usb_on);
    }
```

the crash is like below

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f080066
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:252)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3895)
at com.xmeco.plugseat.widget.PlugSeatCenterView.updateOnStatus(PlugSeatCenterView.java:160)
at com.xmeco.plugseat.widget.PlugSeatCenterView.update(PlugSeatCenterView.java:112)
at com.xmeco.plugseat.widget.PlugSeatCenterView.access$000(PlugSeatCenterView.java:34)
at com.xmeco.plugseat.widget.PlugSeatCenterView$MyHandler.handleMessage(PlugSeatCenterView.java:369)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5049)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line 160 is

```
mStatus.setText(R.string.power_on);
```

I have no idea why this happen. Does anyone met this before? thanks

--------------UPDATE-------

My string.xml(it's in chinese. /res/values/strings.xml. There is only one strings.xml in my project)

```
<string name="power_on">插座电源已开启</string>
<string name="power_off">插座电源已关闭</string>
<string name="usb_on">USB插座已开启</string>
<string name="usb_off">USB插座已开启</string>
```

R.java

```
    public static final int power_off=0x7f080067;
    public static final int power_on=0x7f080066;
    public static final int pull_down_refresh=0x7f080001;
    public static final int refreshing=0x7f080003;
```

Comment: Post your `strings.xml` file here!

Comment: is your string.xml in values/zh ie chinese folder

Comment: use getResources().getString() to obtain String Values from an xml. as per @pRaNaY answer.

Answer (score 0):

**`Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f080066`**

You have to check your `R.java` file to see for the resource with String resource ID `#0x7f080066`, that will explain the reason. If string is not present in file then check if you have string created in your `strings` file. If string is present in `strings` file then clean and rebuild project or otherwise create the string.

That should help, Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this because other answers are mis-directing.

What you are doing is correct! You **CAN** assign the resource identifier of a string from `strings.xml` directly!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

What you need to make sure is that your `strings.xml` has

```
<string name="power_on">Power On</string>
<string name="usb_on">USB On</string>
```

After this rebuild your project and it should work. Hope this helps!

Comment: You're correct that he is using a valid API. However, this is a Runtime crash. If he didn't have the right keys in his strings file his code wouldn't compile.

Comment: You are right. My guess is there was some inconsistency in project build. Rebuilding should solve this problem! :) What do you think?

Comment: I am quite sure there exist these two strings..I used them in other places, even toast. It works fine

Comment: Rebuilding project didn't help? Try replacing the chinese text with English temporarily for identifying if the problem is with the characters!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code like this:-

```
if (mType == Constants.TYPE_POWER) {
    mStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.power_on));
} else if (mType == Constants.TYPE_USB) {
    mStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.usb_on));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here maybe because you only have the resource R.string.power_on in chinese folder (values/zh) and missing the resource for power_on in default folder "values/strings.xml".

Please check your file in folder "values/strings.xml".

This missing resource error usually occur when you support more than 1 language and test with different language in devices.